# .NET - Entity Framework 3.5 - using top/where clauses

Tags: .net, frameworks, entity, where-clause, iqueryable

I'm new to .NET, and I've been asked to make some changes to a project. It's using Entity Framework 3.5.

We currently have a block of code like the following:

```
using (MemphisEquipmentEntities entities = new MemphisEquipmentEntities())
{
    var trucks = entities.Trucks.Top("4");
    truckRepeater.DataSource = trucks;
    truckRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

Instead of grabbing the top 4 trucks, I need to grab the top four trucks where IsSpanish is true. So I wrote the code

```
var trucks = entities.Trucks.Top("4").Where(t => t.IsSpanish == true)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't evaluate in the order I want it to. It pulls the top four trucks out of the table, then checks to see if they're Spanish, and if not, discards them. Switching the top/where clauses doesn't work - it throws an error.

Can anyone lead me in the right direction? My Google skills are failing me, and I'm clueless.

Comment: Move your .Top() to after the .Where() I can't test and get proven code so I won't make this an answer yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var trucks = entities.Trucks.Where(t => t.IsSpanish == true).Take(4);
```

Although you should also sort them, before taking the top 4, but you haven't told us what the sort criteria should be.

NOTE: Take instead of Top

Comment: He uses `Top()` method, mine uses `Take()` method. You are the one who is not reading. They are different methods.